# "two year's " or "two years' " or "two-year"

Tags: possessives, numbers

> In _____ time, criteria for enrolling into university are going to be
>   quite different.

**a) two year's**

**b) two-year**

**c) two years'**

When it comes to me I'd pick **b)** or **c)**, but the source of mine tells that a) is correct.

***I want to know who is wrong and who is right here!***

Comment: Your final version is correct (the possessive attaches to plural ***two years***, which ends with the letter ***s***, so we don't add another after the apostrophe). See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+two+days+time%2Cin+two+day%27s+time%2Cin+two+days%27+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20days%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20day%20%27s%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20days%20%27%20time%3B%2Cc0) comparing *in two **days** time, in two **day's** time, in two **days'** time*.

Comment: (...where no-one would ever have hyphenated *in **two-day** time* - with or without an apostrophe or plural ***days***.)

Comment: The construction is different enough from the potentially duplicate question that the answers do not answer this question.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica You link doesn't work on my end. _"Ngrams not found: in two day &#39;s time, [in two day &#39;s time], in two days &#39; time, [in two days &#39; time]
The Ngram Viewer is case sensitive. Check your capitalization!"_

Comment: @EddieKal: Not sure what happened there. I find it hard to believe I'd have posted a link if it hadn't generated an actual chart, but I can't remember exactly how this one came about. Maybe I cut&pasted the actual "search strings" text into a new NGrams window, but forgot to tick the "Case Insensitive"  checkbox. I sometimes do that with Google Books searches, because the content of the address bar for those  can include irrelevant text from *previous* searches (which I don't think happens with NGrams, but force of habit might have led me to do that anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In **two years**, criteria for enrolling into university are going to be quite different.

This is still idiomatic without "time".

**"Rule":** To add "time", place [apostrophe "s"] after the noun phrase. If the noun phrase is plural and already ends in "s", only place [apostrophe] after it. (Rules for singular words ending in "s" are too complicated to go into here.)

> two years > two years' time
>
> In **two years'** time, criteria for enrolling into university are going to be quite different.

The linked question asks how to insert "day or two" into the following sentence:

> I'll be there in a _____ time.

Again, we can start without "time":

> I'll be there in a **day or two**.

Following the above "rule" we get:

> I'll be there in a **day or two's** time.

Comment: @AlexRaw "In two-year time" sounds very unidiomatic to me. I'd need to see a reference that unambiguously states that for me to accept it. An answer key saying "(b) & (c)" could be a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

**Only (c) is correct.** In possessive expressions of time, an apostrophe goes before the s for one unit of time: one day's pay, one year's time, one month's work. If more than one measure of time is expressed, it goes after the s: two days' pay, two years' time. two months' work.

[Using Apostrophes in Time Expressions](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/apostrophes_in_time_(temporal)_expressions.htm)

Comment: **b)** is the only one that doesn't have an apostrophe at all!

Comment: I think you meant "only (**c**) is correct". I took the liberty of correcting it. Hope you don't mind.